# Pig Script: Null values after join and GENERATE

Tags: hadoop, left-join, apache-pig

I have a strange dilemma in my Pig Script.  I am joining multiple tables and one of the last joins is as follows:

```
a = JOIN O_1 by ((long)OpropID, (long)OAID) LEFT, property by ((long)GPropID, (long)prop_AID);
```

If I filter my result by specific data points, I get the proper results for those fields from the `property` table (right table in the join).  Even without the filter, the resultset is correct, I'm only filtering it to test the results.

```
b = filter a by OpropID==12 and OAID==10;
dump b;
```

However, if create a subsequent `GENERATE` statement immediately after the join, the same fields (last two in the example below) return `NULL` results:

```
c = FOREACH a GENERATE gID, p_AID, OpropID, OAID, GPropID, prop_AID;
```

I've tried using `$16`, `$17` instead of the field names; I've also used `property::GPropID` or `property::prop_AID` to no avail.

Any help at this point would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the results are correct without the filter? Since you are using a `LEFT` join, any records in the first alias which don't have a match in the second will still get carried through, with nulls put in for all the fields of the second alias.

Comment: What I'm saying is that any subsequent GENERATE statements after the JOIN return NULL values for fields in the RIGHT table.  However, if I do an immediate dump after the join, the fields are populated with data.  Hope this clarifies the issue.

Comment: And I am positive that the joins should return correct values, i.e. there is matching data.

Comment: How are you checking this? using Illustrate or running the script? Illustrate might show you some mock data.

Comment: If I dump the output right after the join, it produces valid join output.

Comment: However, if I create a generate statement right after the join and then dump, the output contains null values.

Comment: Illustrate does not work for me, unfortunately, but that is another topic :)

Comment: @Pasha Could you provide some sample data that produces these results?   After the `GENERATE` are there only `NULL`s, where there was data before?  This is very strange.

Comment: I've faced a similar issue in a different script and the only way to "fix" it was to add "DISTINCT" after one of the aliases.  That ensured a proper join between two aliases...  No idea why such behavior....

Comment: can you show what is the schema after joining by using DESCRIBE a